# Keras plot_model replace the question mark by None in the model architecture

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, recurrent-neural-network

I want to get model architecture of the lstm model I am working on. I know the question mark means batch sizes which are not specified so it is displaying question mark but I want it to be replaced by None. Can you please help me with how I can replace the question mark with None because I have mostly seen the batch size shown as None by plot_model? Below is the code I am using and the image I am getting.

```
    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model,
    to_file='model.png',
    show_shapes=True,
    show_layer_names=True
    )
```

[Model Architecture image I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1aBO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your folder where 3rd party packages are, go to

```
tensorflow/keras/utils/vis_utils.py
```

And change line 208-209:

```
def format_shape(shape):
    return str(shape).replace(str(None), '?')
```

Change `'?'` with `'None'`

You can find the source code like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__file__)
```

```
'C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py'
```

Then you can find the right `.py` file.

Comment: Thank you for answering but as I have only used 'utils' because when I included 'utils.vis_utils' it gave an error so I don't have 'tensorflow/keras/utils/vis_utils.py' file and only the 'tensorflow/keras/utils.py' file in which there is no function as def format_shape?

Comment: `C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\vis_utils.py`

Comment: it's tensorflow core... not tensorlfow

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu**
anaconda3/envs/yourEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py

**Windows**
Anaconda\envs\yourEnv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\vis_utils.py

**Change**

```js
def format_shape(shape):
  return str(shape).replace(str(None), '?')
```

**To**

```js
def format_shape(shape):
  return str(shape).replace(str(None), 'None')
```